# Can Swarms/Troops in Pathfinder 1e cast spells and deal damage in the same turn?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, actions, swarm

I'm creating a Troop of casters and wanted to know if they could both deal their "swarm damage" and cast a spell in the same turn.

It makes sense to me since an attack for a swarm reads as follows:

> creatures with the swarm subtype don’t make standard melee attacks. Instead, they deal automatic damage to any creature whose space they occupy at the end of their move, with no attack roll needed.

This means they don't spend their Standard Action to deal damage, it just happens because some of the creatures in the swarm are biting/hitting the target. That leaves other creatures available to do other things.

Am I missing some ruling against this?

Comment: Related: [Is Swarm Attack an action?](/questions/39613)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes

Specifically, Troops *automatically* deal damage to enemies within their space and within reach.

> Troop Attack: Creatures with the troop subtype **don’t make standard melee attacks**. Instead, **they deal automatic damage to any creature within reach or whose space they occupy at the end of their move, with no attack roll needed.** A troop’s stat block has “troop” in its Melee entry with no attack bonus given. The amount of damage a troop deals is based on its Hit Dice. Unless stated otherwise, a troop’s attacks are non-magical. Damage Reduction sufficient to reduce a troop attack’s damage to 0 or other special abilities can give a creature immunity (or at least resistance) to the troop’s attacks. Some troops also have other special attacks in addition to normal damage. Troops threaten all creatures within their reach or within their area, and attempt attacks of opportunity as normal with their troop attack.

There is no action associated, so it does not cost any actions to do this.